# Some records are deleting automatically after some point in time from the Android SQLite database with Sugar ORM

Tags: android, android-sqlite, sugarorm

I am working on an android application that is using for collecting data. We have realized now a new issue, some records are missing from the database after some days/weeks. We used the SQLite database with Sugar ORM.

Comment: Need further explanation and code snippets

Comment: Code is something like creating new model object which is extends sugar record and call save method. We are able to see this records in database after saving the records. But after some days some records are not available in database, not all the records. Is there any scenario can be this issue like updating the app or some other cases? And We have used Mobile Device management to install and update the app, is it the issue from Mobile Device management?